# How to link external framework of XCODE project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have an private framework for my project and that private framework I have to link with XCODE; means if I am doing any changes in framework code it will automatically reflect to framework used in the project.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you maintain a separate repo for your private framework (as I understand it's gonna be used in different projects). For example, if you use git, just add it as submodule to your project and then reference it from there. (use relative paths only!).

This way you can keep enhancing your framework as you work with it so you can commit hotfixes, work on new features and test it while working on your projects, in a very natural way.

Comment: Yes I create subfolder inside the repo. After this all good or have to load binary or anything

Comment: What I usually do is to create a subfolder in my project called submodules, in which I reference all the external repos I'm using: git submodule add git://path/to/repo.git submodules/repo

Comment: Yes I did the same. So is it ok or we have to do some thing more

Comment: I think that should be enough. As a side note, I'd recommend Atlassian's excellent Sourcetree as the git client, it works perfectly with submodules (while others struggle significantly more, but this is just a personal opinion)